# Modifying covariance structure in statsmodels mixedLM

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, linear-model, statsmodels

I am using the following command to fit a linear mixed model for repeated measures (MMRM) in statsmodels:

```py
smf.mixedlm("RESPONSE ~ C(TIME) + GROUP + C(TIME)*GROUP", data, groups=data['ID'])
```

I would like to do this with an unstructured covariance matrix. What is the default in statsmodels? Can I modify it to unstructured?